# How can I make the WifiClient.connect work in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, android-wifi, android-bluetooth

I would like to know if WifiClient.connect does not allow the locally running server to be connected (e.g. http://localhost:8080). I discovered that WifiClient.connect works when the url is anything public (e.g. www.google.com). Please help if there may be something I can programmatically change in order to connect the localhost server. The code below is a portion of `setup()`.

```
status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

// if you're not connected, stop here:
if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
  Serial.println("Couldn't get a wifi connection");
  while(true);
} 
// if you are connected, print out info about the connection:
else {
  Serial.println("Connected to network");
}

// configure the uri to be called
char apiURL[] = "127.0.0.1";

uint16_t port = 8080;    

if (client.connect(apiURL, port)){
  Serial.println("connected to " + String(apiURL)); 
  // it always prints this statement
}else{
  Serial.println("not calling " + String(apiURL));
}
```

One more (and maybe silly) thing I would like to ask: would Bluetooth be a better option than Wifi when I want my Arduino to send data to server (e.g. making POST request)?

Comment: Why would you need to connect an Arduino back to the same Arduino?

Comment: Oh it's not I'm connecting to the same board. There is another application running locally at port 8080. I would like to see if the WifiClient can connect to that application.

Comment: You don't seem to know what [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) actually means.